# Maximum value of a probability function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Ten fish are caught in a lake, marked, and then returned to the lake. Two days
later $20$ fish are again caught, two of which have been marked.

Find the probability of two of the $20$ fish being marked if the lake has $k$ fish
(assuming the fish are caught at random).

we need to take $2$ fishes from marked $10$ fishes, which can be done in ${10 \choose 2}$ ways. Then rest $18$ fishes will be chosen from rest $k-10$ unmarked fishes. Therefore the probability is

$$\frac{{10 \choose 2}{k-10 \choose 18}}{k \choose 20}$$

But the problem asks for Which value of "$k$" the probability will be maximum.

I am totally stuck as this function becomes very lengthy to solve.

Help appreciated :)

Comment: This is an instance of [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood). With the help of a computer, your $\hat k$ maximizing probability of the event (or [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)) is $99$ or $100$. Are you supposed to find it by hand?

Comment: yes exactly ..I need to find it by hand

Comment: @JKnecht But that answer could have been more specific. I feel it has not been answered properly.

Comment: Yes, it has. Your probability $p(k)$ is difficult to manage, but $p(k+1)/p(k)$ is easy: almost all factors disappear.

Comment: @ViX28 Ok, thats no longer up for me to decide, i flagged it.

Comment: @ViX28 You could ask a new question if you get stuck doing that calculation. But it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: @ViX28 I'll give you a hint. The number you are looking for is somewhere in this comment section :)

Comment: @JKnecht Actually, both $99$ and $100$ maximize the likelihood. However, the [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_%28statistics%29) would yield $100$ (the expectation of the number $N$ of marked fishes the second day is $200/k$, equate it to $2$, and you find $k=100$).